# QMainWindow open very late

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have `open_customer_phone_number` window in pyqt5 application when I type number and press sendVideoBtn, I need to run send_video function. It working but when I press this button I need to open new window with `open_info_window`. But `window4` openning very late, I showw `---Process--l`og and after that open window4. how can I solve this problem ?

```
   def open_customer_phone_number_window(self,filename):
        self.window3 = QMainWindow()
        self.phoneUi = Ui_PhoneMainWindow()
        self.phoneUi.setupUi(self.window3)
        self.window3.show()
        print(filename)
        self.phoneUi.sendVideoBtn.clicked.connect(partial(self.send_video,filename))

    def open_info_window(self):
        self.window3.close()

        self.window4 = QMainWindow()
        self.sendInfoUi = Ui_SendInfoMainWindow()
        self.sendInfoUi.setupUi(self.window4)
        self.window4.show() # it showing very late

    def send_video(self,filename):
        USER_PHONE = self.phoneUi.phoneNumber.text()
        FILE_NAME = filename
        self.open_info_window()
        print("--Process---")
        for i in range(101):
          time.sleep(0.05)
        # setting value to progress bar
          self.sendInfoUi.progressBar.setValue(i)
```

Comment: What you do in `send_video` is most certainly blocking the event loop, so the window doesn't show/redraw until the function ends. You should probably move what you do in `--Process---` in a QThread with proper signals.

Comment: what I add after the process text for example I now add to topic progress bar. Window4 openning after progress bar completed. When it is working window4 showing to me as a white screen

Comment: That doesn't matter, you're still **blocking** the event loop, especially since you're using `time.sleep()`. As already said, if you need to do some processing there, you must use QThread.